# how to get keypress from one window into another?

Tags: events, window, keypress, nw.js

I've been trying to get the keypress from one window into another. Since a window gets focused, the other window can't receive my keypresses, so I want to pass those to the window that needs them. I can't figure out how to do this.
I've tried window.eval() and simulating a keypress, but there doesn't appear anyway to simulate a keypress successfully in node webkit. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i think the best solution is to focus on the window that needs to be focused instead of transfering events between windows which can be done but it is a mess

Comment: I've tried this, but it causes the windows to flash/flicker since there is a lot of interaction between windows. I need a way to do it without focusing the window.

Comment: then have a callback on the unfocused window which receives event data from the other window and process them. Then the actually focused window can have a `keypress` handler which takes the event and passes it to the callback above. However this can  create interactivity confusion to the user

Comment: yeah, I guess I'll have to just pass the key, and whether the ctrl,alt,shift is held, and then do stuff based on the data rather than try to simulate a keypress. :\

Comment: you can still *soft* trigger a `keypress` event on the unfocused window if you want by using `jQuery('whatever').trigger('keypress')` and pass the event data from other window as well